# Asp.Net MVC Display index list according to settings in another table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an index page that displays a list of parts with current prices. What I need is to have selling price multiplied by whatever the setting is for that. There are different price ranges on different items. What I need to do is get the starting letter of the `PartNumber` and compare it to the list in the settings.

For instance a part that is A01282 when the part is retrieved I need to get the first letter and compare it with the value.

In my controller I have this so far but am unable to figure out how to compare the two of them. I am also having issues trying to get the part number. It is saying it doesn't exist in the `IEnumerable`.

Here is my  controller action so far.

```
public ActionResult Index(Guid id)
{
    var productMaster = db.ProductMaster.Include(p => p.Parts).Include(p => p.Vendor);
    var prodData = db.Parts.Include(n => n.PartNumber);
    var Billsettings = db.BillingSettings.Where(t => t.Types == 1).OrderByDescending(m => m.StartingValues).FirstOrDefault();


    return View(productMaster.ToList().Where(m => m.Material == id));
}
```

So after the `var Billingsettings` I would put an `if` statement that does the compare.

To each of these `partnumbers` that match the starting letter in settings would get the `AverageCost` in `ProductMaster` multiplied by the settings value for selling price.

If someone could help point me in the right direction that would be great.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:
Model classes:

```
public class ProductMaster
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ProductMasterId { get; set; }
    public Guid VendorId { get; set; }
    public Guid Material { get; set; }
    public string VendorRef { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime? LastUpdated { get; set; }

    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "UOM")]
    public string UnitOfMeasure { get; set; }
    //[Display(Name = "Sell Price")]
    //public decimal SellingPrice { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Cost")]
    public decimal StandardCost { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Avg Cost")]
    public decimal AverageCost { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Last Cost")]
    public decimal LastCost { get; set; }
    public bool IsPrimary { get; set; }
    public string LeadTime { get; set; }

    public Vendors Vendor { get; set; }
    public Parts Parts { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public class BillingSettings
{
    [Key]
    public Guid BillingSettingsId { get; set; }

    public int Types { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string StartingValues { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the settings table:
[image: Settings Table]

UPDATE: I Changed the `Value` column in the table to `Money`. So they are correct now.

UPDATE: To follow what was given below I have made these changes.
However it does not work. The `'?'` after `(x.Key))` gives this error:

> Operator '?' cannot be applied to operaand of type
>   'KeyVAluePair'

Here is what I have:

```
public ActionResult Index(Guid id)
{
    //var productMaster = db.ProductMaster.Include(p => p.Parts).Include(p => p.Vendor);

    var dict = db.BillingSettings.Where(t => t.Types == 1).ToDictionary(x => x.StartingValues, x => x.Value);

    var price = db.Parts.Include(n => n.ProdMaster).ToList().Where(m => m.Material == id).Select(n => {
        n.SellingPrice = n.ProdMaster.AverageCost * (dict.FirstOrDefault(x => n.PartNumber.StartsWith(x.Key))?.Value ?? 1);
        //return n;
    });

    //return View(productMaster.ToList().Where(m => m.Material == id));
    return View(price);
}
```

UPDATE: Still kinda stuck with this. I need this to return a view with the Guid. Although the below answer has been helpful, it has also confused me as to what I am supposed to do with it. Put it in a model? Call the Model from the controller?

Below is my parts Model:

```
public class Parts
{
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "Part")]
    public Guid Material { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Drawing")]
    public string DrawingNumber { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Extended")]
    public string ExtDescription { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Image")]
    public string PartImage { get; set; }

    public bool ShowPrice { get; set; }
    public string PartNumber { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Stock")]
    public int? UnitsInStock { get; set; }
    public bool? Status { get; set; }

    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }

    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }

    public bool? IsDelete { get; set; }

    //public virtual ProductMaster ProdMaster { get; set; }

    public virtual List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
}
```

UPDATE:
Taking what was given to me below this is what I am looking for or some variation of it. It does not like the `'select(N =>'` so this does not work. Any help on this would be appreciated..

```
public ActionResult Index(Guid id)
{
    var dict = db.BillingSettings.Where(t => t.Types == 1).Select(x => new { x.StartingValues, x.Value });

    var productMaster = db.ProductMaster.Include(p => p.Parts).Include(p => p.Vendor).Include(p => p.BillSettings).Where(m => m.Material == id).Select(n =>
    { 
        n.SellingPrice = n.AverageCost * (dict.FirstOrDefault(x => n.Parts.PartNumber.StartsWith(x.StartingValues))?.Value ?? 1);

    });

    return View(productMaster.ToList());
}
```

Error I am getting says:

> The type argument for method 'Queryable.Select(IQueryable, Expression>)'
>   cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type argument
>   explicitly.

UPDATE: 
Since i am unable to figure this out and there does not seem to be anyone else that can figure this out, I have changed the format to use a stored procedure to automatically calculate the selling price for me - On button-click and on Update. Along with with a build view - All server side SQL.

I still need some work on this but this is the start. It works but is not pretty!

```
SELECT pm.[ProductMasterId]
  ,pm.[Material]
  ,pm.[UnitOfMeasure]
  ,pm.[StandardCost]
  ,pm.[AverageCost]
  ,pm.[LastCost]
  ,pm.[IsPrimary]
  ,pm.[LeadTime]
  ,CASE
    WHEN priceMatch.[Value] IS NOT NULL
    THEN pm.LastCost * priceMatch.[Value]
    ELSE pm.LastCost * (SELECT TOP 1 [Value] FROM [dbo].[BillingSettings] WHERE [Types] = 1 AND [StartingValues] IS NULL)
    END AS [SellingPrice]
  ,p.[PartNumber]
  FROM [dbo].[ProductMaster] pm
  INNER JOIN [dbo].[Parts] p
  ON pm.[Material] = p.Material
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT [StartingValues]
              ,[Value]
          FROM [dbo].[BillingSettings]
          WHERE [Types] = 1
          AND [StartingValues] IS NOT NULL) AS priceMatch
  ON SUBSTRING(p.PartNumber, 1, 1) = priceMatch.[StartingValues]
```

Comment: it might help if you posted the POCO model classes in question

Answer (score 0):

So what you need is.

First, build a Dictionary using

```
var dict = db.BillingSettings.Where(t => t.Types == 1).ToDictionary(x => x.StartingValue, x => x.Value)
```

Then, when selecting the parts, do the comparison

```
db.Parts.Include(n => n.ProductMaster).ToList().Select(n => {
    n.SellingPrice = n.ProductMaster.AverageCost * (dict.FirstOrDefault(x => n.PartNumber.StartsWith(x.Key))?.Value ?? 1);
    return n;
});
```

UPDATE:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dbContext = new FakeDbContext();

        var lookup = dbContext.BillingSettings.Where(t => t.Types == 1).Select(s => new
        {
            s.StartingValues,
            s.Value
        });

        var price = dbContext.Parts
            //.Include(n => n.ProdMaster).ToList() // this will work with real EF DbContext
            //.Where(m => m.Material == id) // this will work with real EF DbContext
            .Select(n =>
            {
                n.SellingPrice = n.ProductMaster.AverageCost * (lookup.FirstOrDefault(x => n.PartNumber.StartsWith(x.StartingValues))?.Value ?? 1);
                return n;
            });

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class FakeDbContext
{
    public List<Part> Parts { get; set; }
    public List<BillingSettings> BillingSettings { get; set; }
}

public class ProductMaster
{
    public decimal AverageCost { get; set; }
}

public class Part
{
    public ProductMaster ProductMaster { get; set; }
    public decimal SellingPrice { get; set; }
    public string PartNumber { get; set; }
}

public class BillingSettings
{
    public int Types { get; set; }
    public string StartingValues { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. And Welcome to the site! So Parts does not contain ProductMaster and I do not have Selling price in the model. So should i put this in a ViewModel and add what i need to it? Also with what you have am i using this and scratching what is currently in the controller?

Comment: Couple of other things. the '?' after (x.Key)) says it cannot be used with type 'KeyValuePAir<string, decimal>'. And i would still need to return the list where material == id.

Comment: If you can add your Part model, so I can help. Because in your LinQ, there is SellingPrice from Part model. :) I may misunderstand your model

Comment: I just added an update. I changed not to use Dictionary anymore, instead, I use dynamic type. But hope you got the idea how to use 1 list to lookup inside another list.

Comment: I added the BillingSettings to the parts model. However i think that will give me other issues. Could you please implement how i would use what you have in a controller returning the view?? Or is it as easy as replacing Console.ReadKey with Return View(price); thanks

Comment: I don't even know what do you want to display on the View. The solution gives you a list of Parts, in each part, the selling price is calculated by looking up in the BillingSettings.

Comment: In the original part at the top i have a working controller action. It brings back a list of vendors with prices on the part, providing that their are more than 1 vendor for the part. It will most likely just bring back the primary vendor with prices. The only thing it lacks is the selling price which needs to be evaluated and calculated from the BillingSettings. That it. The view Action works without the Selling Price.